# Making function recursive

Tags: .net, recursion, f#, functional-programming

I have a function

```
let simpleSum n =
    let s = n * (n+1)/2
    printf "%A " s
let result = simpleSum 10
```

I now want to make it recursive; tail-recursion without added variables is preferred.
There is something wrong with my statement: `if n <= 0 then 0`

```
 let rec recSum n = 
     if n <= 0 then
         0
     else
         recSum n*(n+1)/2
 recSum 4
```

I run into the error:

```
FS0020: The result of this expression is implicitly ignored. 
Consider using 'ignore' to discard this value explicitly, e.g. 'expr :> ignore',
or 'let' to bind the result to a name, e.g. 'let result = expr'.
```

How do I fix this?  I want to avoid variables.

Comment: What's not working? what errors/issues are you running into?

Comment: What's the point of that while loop? In which cases would the result be any different than just `let sum n = n * (n+1) / 2`?

Comment: The while loop is not necessary I know, but was a requirement in my assignment. 
I run into the error:

FS0020: The result of this expression is implicitly ignored. Consider using 'ignore' to discard this value explicitly, e.g. 'expr :> ignore', or 'let' to bind the result to a name, e.g. 'let result = expr'.

I want to avoid variables here.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't misunderstand your assignment? You can either calculate the sum using a loop/recursion *or* you can use the formula. Doing both at the same time makes no sense.

Comment: First assignment was to use a loop. Second assignment was to use recursion. Right now I am just trying to make the recursion work. The sum should add up to the same.

Comment: you should also indent your code 4 spaces, makes it easier to read.

Comment: In Visual Studio and VSCode pressing tab in F# gives you four spaces.

Comment: But was the assignment to use the formula you're using? Or was it to use loops and recursion in a normal/sane way?

Comment: The assignment is just to find the sum of 1 + 2 +  ... +n using recursion.
Dont worry too much about my code above, since it is most likely wrong in so many ways. I am trying to figure this thing out.

Comment: Then you're not currently solving the assignment. Again: your loop solution does not actually ever loop (except in the case where it loops infinitely). If the assignment is just to write a loop that sums the numbers from 1 to n, you should just do that and get rid of the formula. Once you did that, you can can rewrite that loop as a recursion. But as long as your loop-version is not actually looping, you can only ever end up with a recursive version that never actually recurs, which would not be in the spirit of the assignment.

Comment: Alright so I removed the while loop. But still running in to all kinds of trouble when trying to make it recursive.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39698430/f-how-to-call-a-function-with-argument-byref-int. It has a reclusive implementation.

Comment: I took a look at it, and I cant find the reason why I am getting the FS0020 error message:
The result of this expression is implicitly ignored. Consider using 'ignore' to discard this value explicitly, e.g. 'expr :> ignore', or 'let' to bind the result to a name, e.g. 'let result = expr'.

There is something wrong with my statement:    if n <= 0 then 0

Answer (score 2):

I am not going to do your assignment for you. However, I will show you the usual way to transform a loop into a recursive function.

This is the "imperative" way to do a factorial.

```
let factorial n = 
    let mutable acc = 1
    let mutable iter = 1 
    while iter <= n do 
        acc <- acc * iter
        iter <- iter + 1 
    acc
```

And here it is in a recursive implementation :

```
let recFactorial n = 
    let rec loop acc iter = 
        if iter > n then acc else 
        loop (acc*iter) (iter+1) 
    loop 1 1
```

You will see I defined the actual recursive function inside my bigger function. I believe it makes the code cleaner this way.

There are many ways, subtly different, to change a `while` or `for` loop into a recursive function, but this I think shows you how the one-to-one relationship works.

Your code gets stuck in an infinite loop when I call `sum 1` btw. Crashed my editor.

Edit: Incidentally, the "naïve" way to do a Factorial recursive function is this

```
let rec recFactorial n = 
    if n = 1 then 1 else 
    n * recFactoiral (n-1)
```

However, this is not recommended and *will* crash your program quickly due to stack overflow. Any article on Tail Recursion (what I did the first time) will explain why this is in a much better way than I can.